# Switch case problem in Arduino code

Tags: ir, switch

I am trying to develop an IR remote for appliances. I have written Arduino code for this purpose. I have used switch case to determine an action from the corresponding IR decode result (HEX), but I am not getting the output.

My code is:

```
#include <IRremote.h>

int RECV_PIN = 6;
int led = 13;//1FE50AF
int led1 = 12;//1FED827 

boolean previousState=LOW;
boolean previousState1=LOW;
boolean state;
boolean state1;
IRrecv irrecv(RECV_PIN);

decode_results results;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(12,OUTPUT);
  irrecv.enableIRIn();// Start the receiver 
}

void loop() {
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) {
    Serial.println(results.value, HEX);
    switch(results.value) {
       case '0x1FE50AF':
       if (previousState == LOW) {
         state=HIGH;
         digitalWrite(led,state);
         Serial.println("LED ON");
         previousState=state;
       } else {
         state=LOW;
         digitalWrite(led,state);
         Serial.println("LED Off");
         previousState=state;
       }
       break;

       case '0x1FED827':
       if (previousState1 == LOW) {
         state=HIGH;
         digitalWrite(led1,state1);
         Serial.println("LED ON");
         previousState1=state1;
       } else {
         state1=LOW;
         digitalWrite(led1,state1);
         Serial.println("LED off");
         previousState1=state1;
       }
       break;
    }   
    irrecv.resume(); // Receive the next value
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arduino.SX. You can use { } on top of the editor bar to mark you code so they all become readable between text and codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all:

```
case '0xZZZZZZZZ':
```

with:

```
case 0xZZZZZZZZ:
```

That's because `value` in `decode_results` structure is declared as `unsigned long`, `0xZZZZZZZZ` is an `unsigned long`, but `'0xZZZZZZZZ'` is not (actually, it should not even compile).